# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.displaytag.tags.TableTagExtraInfo in struts 1.2

Tags: jsp, struts

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" prefix="display" %>
<display:table id="data" name="sessionData.actorList" requestURI="/baseLife_processInsuredPhone.do" decorator="com.mccamish.web.appentry.base_life.displayTable.ActorDecorator" pagesize="6" >
        <display:column property="tvShow" title="TV Show" />
        <display:column property="userName" title="User Name" />
        <display:column property="emailId" title="Email Id" />
    </display:table>
```

I have used this code in JSP for display table but before showing this JSP page i am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.displaytag.tags.TableTagExtraInfo` Exception and this Error `ERROR ServletException in '/pages/appEntry/baseLife/HUF.jsp': org.displaytag.tags.TableTagExtraInfo
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagExtraInfo class: org.displaytag.tags.TableTagExtraInfo`
I have imported `displaytag-1.2.jar` but still i am getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

I have included jar files in class path but still don't why that exception was came.
Then i have included jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder and my exception is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the same jar file is available to deployment assembly and will have run time availability.